OpenMP causing issues with nested parallelism
Hello I am encountering a strange issue with OpenMP, I have the following scenario :
I have several regular std::thread threads running in parallel, at some point during the execution of these threads I am doing some calls to OpenCV functions which are using OpenMP, if I don't use OpenMP anywhere else in my code everything runs fine, however if I use OpenMP at any point during the execution of those threads those portions of code do not actually seem to be parallelized at all and the overhead causes even worse performance.
At first I thought that this has something to do OpenMP not supporting nested parallelism but my segments of code which use OpenMP do not contain calls to the OpenCV library. Regardless it's clear that my use of OpenMP is interfering somehow with whatever the OpenMP runtime is doing.
I tried using omp_set_nested(1) but apparently this is deprecated and it tells me to use omp_set_max_active_levels instead but I am not sure how to use this either in this context. I am using MSVC compiler.
Any suggestions ?
void func(...) {
   ...
   cv::dct(img, img, 0); // this is the opencv call in question that's using OpenMP
   ...

   #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(numThreads) schedule(dynamic)
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       // this is the place in the code where I explicitly use OpenMP in each thread
   }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv)
{

    std::vector<std::thread> Tasks(3);
    
    //these threads run in parallel 
    Tasks[0] = std::thread(func,...);
    Tasks[1] = std::thread(func,...);
    Tasks[2] = std::thread(func,...);
    ...

    SetThreadAffinityMask(Tasks[0].native_handle(), ...);
    SetThreadAffinityMask(Tasks[1].native_handle(), ...);
    SetThreadAffinityMask(Tasks[2].native_handle(), ...);


Please provide a [mcve]. Without code we are left with guesswork and crystal balls. And the last time I saw someone with a working crystal ball here is long time ago

Is it the same issue as this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65743267/does-opencv-suppress-openmp?noredirect=1#comment116352635_65743267

Nesting is a long-standing well-known problem. It should be avoided as much as possible nowadays since it generally causes performance issue and is still poorly supported by some OpenMP implementations. The standard solution is to move to tasks. Quand you parallelise a code calling some external library, the common solution is to execute function of the target library in sequential (possibly even build the library so to be always sequential if parallel functions is not rarely useful). Thread over-subscription is as bad as barrier + starvation (worst on some platform because it is sneaky).

Sorry that I can't provide the exact code because it's quite extensive but I edited my post with a rough outline of what it is that I am doing.

@Micka Seems possible related, it's not quite the same issue, for example omp_get_max_threads() returns the correct number of threads in my case and as long as I don't make certain calls to opencv like dct or idct everything works fine, just linking the library doesn't affect anything.

Upon closer inspection I am not even sure my OpenCV build is using OpenMP I just assumed it does, getBuildInformation just says :   Parallel framework:  Concurrency , this makes all this even stranger. I'll see if I can get a build that uses explicitly OpenMP to see if I get the same problem.

Maybe opencv in concurrency mode is actively "disabling" openmp by some environmental variable settings?

If omp_max_threads() returns >1, openmp will try to spawn threads for you, but this is an upper limit. Since you spawn multiple c++ threads, all threads will count towards the thread limit, so check what limit you might have there. Msvc + the deprecation message about nested hints on llvm openmp runtime. Try KMP_HOT_TEAMS_MAX_LEVEL=2 to keep threads from multiple teams alive between parallel regions.
